# Use $_POST data in functions.php

Tags: forms

I want to pass a parameter to a page from the one visited before and use it in a shortcode function. For this, I am writing in the scope of a function in functions.php :

`$currency=$_POST['currency']`

But it always return empty. What is the correct way to do this ?

EDIT:

My guess is that functions.php has an empty $_POST when called as it is called by an other file, not directly by the user. How can I access the _POST data in functions.php then ?

Comment: And how are you passing this value? $_POST is availabe with POST requests only. If you don't use POST request from one page to another, $_POST will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding you query variable to the public query variable list like this.

```
function wp280272_query_vars($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'currency';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wp280272_query_vars' );
```

you then can access it via

```
get_query_var('currency');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! In what file should I writte this bit of code ? In functions.php ?

Comment: Ok, I used this in functions.php and it worked, thanks !